# How to format sting in root.plist?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, format, plist

Is there a way to format a string in the root.plist file? I have looked everywhere and I'm shocked there's nothing on this. All I want to do is center this:

```
<string>Version 1.1</string>
```

That way it's centered when going into the settings app for my app settings.(Hope that makes sense.)

Any help would be great, I can't believe there's nothing on doing this!

Answer led me to this: Works Great!

```
<dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
    <key>FooterText</key>
    <string>Version 1.1</string>
    <key>Key</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this in the past by putting what I want in a new group as `Footertext`

```
<dict>
    <key>FooterText</key>
    <string>Centered Text Here</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
</dict>
```

Caveat - This will result in some whitespace between this group and any other groups.